# Create Route to Simple Page Reaction Commerce

Tags: meteor, reaction-commerce

I am trying to setup a simple static page for about us, based on this tutorial (https://docs.reactioncommerce.com/reaction-docs/master/plugin-routes-6).  The problem is that there is no real explanation on what I need to do outside adding an entry to the registry.js file.  While they do have the plugin example that I could copy, I would like to know what I need to just add a simple static page to Reaction Commerce.  Thanks.

Wade

Answer (score 1):

To create the simple route for the page, given [tutorial](https://docs.reactioncommerce.com/reaction-docs/master/plugin-routes-6) is what we all got.

**To Create route for a page:** 
I will break it down for you in following steps:

I will assume that you know we have to add our code in the **/imports/plugin/custom** directory only. You can override all the core functionality from here.

Let's get started:

1. You need to add route details in the registry under register.js file.

   ```
   registry:[
       {
           route:"/about",
           name:"about",
           template:"aboutUs",
           workflow:"coreWorkflow"
       }
   ],
   ```
2. Create the component for a new page as

   **/imports/plugin/custom/YOUR_PLUGIN/client/components/about.js** in your plugin.

   ```
   import React, { Component } from "react";
   import { registerComponent } from "/imports/plugins/core/components/lib";
   import { Meteor } from "meteor/meteor";
   import { Col } from 'reactstrap';

   class About extends Component {

     render() {
       return (
         <div className="container-main">
           About Us Page
         </div>
       );
     }
   }

   registerComponent("about", About);
   ```
3. Add the button to route to the new page, in any component, from where you can give link to About page.

   ```
   <Components.Button
       label="About"
       onClick={handleClick}
   />
   ```
4. Add function to handle the click.

   ```
   handleClick() {
       return Reaction.Router.go("/about");
   }
   ```

Hope this solves your query!

PS: I know this code can be shortened, I have written it in this way so that beginners can understand it faster. Please don't hesitate to correct the answer if I am wrong. :)